# Autoupdate changes into Azure devops from github repository

Tags: azure, github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, github-actions

I have a repository in Github and want to integrate it into Azure-DevOps. I connected both the repositories in Github as well as Azure-devops.
When I commit some code into Github the changes are not getting updated automatically in Azure. Is there anyway that we can automatically pull the changes if there are any new changes in Github?

Any references/suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: The execution totally depends upon the trigger. Kindly see what you have defined over there, and you are pushing changes in correct branch. For triggers - [see this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers)

Comment: Could you please clarify how you 'integrate Github repo and Azure DevOps', do you mean Github repo as the pipeline source? "Is there anyway that we can automatically pull the changes if there are any new changes in Github?", Could you please clarify the situation you encountered.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

Azure DevOps doesn't have such a built-in feature to sync the Github repo to the DevOps repo now.

If you need the feature, you can upvote the feature request in this place:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/automatically-sync-azure-devops-repository-with-gi/516057

When enough people request a new feature, Microsoft will include it in future product plans.

***1, You need to use code/script to sync the repo and use the CI Trigger of the YAML pipeline to capture the changes in the Github repo.***

```
trigger:
- <branch name>

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
- name: system.debug
  value: true

steps:
- script: |
    echo put the logic here
  displayName: 'Push changes to DevOps repo'
```

The code you can refer to this page:

https://dileepveldi.medium.com/sync-azure-devops-repo-with-github-repo-35a958d7784e

***2, Then after the above pipeline pushes the changes, you need to captrue the changes via the CI trigger of the YAML pipeline on DevOps side.***

```
trigger:
- <branch name>

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
- name: system.debug
  value: true

steps:
- script: |
    echo xxx
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
```

**Original Answer:**

If you mean integrating Github repo and Azure DevOps pipeline, for example, you need continuous integration on main branch of your repo.

Then, follow the below steps.

1, For classic pipeline:

[image]

2, For YAML pipeline:

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
```

If what you mean is not integrating Github repo and Azure DevOps pipeline, please clarify your requirements.

Comment: When I commit something into Github the changes are to be pulled into Azure DevOps repository automatically and some builds should trigger.

Comment: @VineelPellella From your description, it should be CI trigger on the Azure DevOps side.

Comment: Can you guide me with navigation steps

Comment: @VineelPellella Hi Vineel, any update on this question, have you checked my answer, does my answer answered your question?

Comment: I am looking for an automated process which is not available as of now in Azure pipelines